# not able to install laravel

Tags: laravel, installation

[image]

I am not able to install laravel on my system .i have attached image along with query

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://packagist.org/p/provider-2017-10%24c2da5c82073ff36a0c3e2ab10e7a64132a6a9ec5a4d8036e0b9b74108a6e0f8d.jso
  n" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [] [] []

Comment: This is caused by the network. This means that your proxy configuration is incorrect. May be unable to resolve DNS. check your network and proxy setting if any.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your composer using the command - composer selfupdate

Comment: Give us the complete answer with an example